# cocos2d CCMenu padding strange on retina device

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, retina-display

**Situation:**
I'm using [(CCMenu*)myMenu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:4.0f] to layout several buttons (CCMenuItemSprite) vertically. On non-retina device the padding appears as expected, but when in retina mode on simulator the padding seems to be doubled. Any ideas as to why?

**Code:**

```
CCMenuItemSprite *itemPlay = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"play.png"] selectedSprite:nil target:self selector:@selector(goPlay:)];

CCMenuItemSprite *itemHowto = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"howto.png"] selectedSprite:nil target:self selector:@selector(goHowto:)];

CCMenuItemSprite *itemSettings = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"settings.png"] selectedSprite:nil target:self selector:@selector(goSettings:)];

CCMenuItemSprite *itemHelp = [CCMenuItemSprite itemFromNormalSprite:[CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"help.png"] selectedSprite:nil target:self selector:@selector(goHelp:)];

CCMenu *myMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:itemPlay,itemHowto,itemSettings,itemHelp, nil];
myMenu.position = ccp(160.0f,216.0f);
[myMenu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:4.0f];
[self addChild: myMenu z:10];
```

**Update:** 
I'd hate to do something like this but I will if no better solution exists:

```
float padding = 4.0f;
// flag stored in app delegate to know whether we are retina
if([[AppDelegate sharedAppDelegate] isRetina])padding = (2.0f);
CCMenu *myMenu = [CCMenu menuWithItems:itemPlay,itemHowto,itemSettings,itemHelp, nil];
myMenu.position = ccp(160.0f,216.0f);
[myMenu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:padding];
[self addChild: myMenu z:10];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solved:**
The padding problem was created by a setting in TexturePacker. I had 'inner padding' set to a value of 4px. Removing the setting fixed the problem. See screenshot below:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

i dont have much experience with cocos2d but you can try this:

```
[myMenu alignItemsVerticallyWithPadding:(4.0f/[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale])];
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have retina assets? cocos2d will not auto scale up your assets, so it's your CCSprite that was half the size, hence the padding seems to be doubled.

Comment: Yes I have retina assets in a spritesheet (created by TexturePacker)